# Split multiple email address and output to 3 columns (username, domain, extension) in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres and would like to learn how to split multiple email address at once and the final table ouput would have 3 columns username, domain, extension.

For example I have multiple email address.

`robert.bryne@gmail.com` and so forth

I need an output on the table like this.

| username | domain | extension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| robert bryne | gmail | com |

Also, how do I insert into with all of this select results in my table.

Comment: Maybe `unnest` and `string_to_array` might help! Maybe something like `SELECT unnest(string_to_array('robert.bryne@gmail.com', '@')) AS parts;` Then maybe you need to do something on the second half. But this logic won't hold I'd say since the second half could have anything! Like even periods in between, ie. `foobar@multi.corp.com` idk?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [REGEXP_MATCHES](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-regexp_matches-function/) to match email address, then retrieve each email part in matched result.

```
WITH data AS 
    (SELECT 'robert.bryne@gmail.com' AS email, 
     REGEXP_MATCHES('robert.bryne@gmail.com', 
       '^(\w+[\.-]?\w+)*@(\w+[\.-]?\w+)*\.(\w{2,3})+$', 'g') AS email_parts)
SELECT REPLACE(email_parts[1], '.', ' ') AS username,  
       email_parts[2] AS domain,
       email_parts[3] AS extension
FROM data;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/n2cRGwQs)

Comment: Thank you very much, Trung Duong. The output you have is what I need exactly. But, how about if there is a bulk email address that I insert into a table name Email with a single column with the column name email_address. Will this still work or do I have to do this one at a time?

Comment: @Trevo  Yes, it still works in case of selecting data from a table. I've updated my demo to select data from a table, please check. https://dbfiddle.uk/n2cRGwQs

Comment: It worked! You are a rockstar, Trung Duong!

Answer (score 0):

You can use split_part

```
select split_part(email, '@', 1) as username, 
       split_part(split_part(email, '@', 2), '.', 1) as domain, 
       split_part(split_part(email, '@', 2), '.', 2) as extension
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already done this spli_part but to combine firstname and lastname for different columns to a single one column is the challenge for a newbie like me :)